# users does not define no argument constructor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i kept getting this error
"users does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped." Tried everything, no idea why it happen.

```
public void retrievingUserInfo(){

    databaseUserID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous userinfo list
            Users_Info.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting userinfo
                users userinfo = postSnapshot.getValue(users.class);
                //adding userinfo to the list
                Users_Info.add(userinfo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

users.class

```
@Keep
public class users {

    public String user_id, address, contact, name;

    public users(String user_id, String address, String contact,String name) 
    {}


}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

JavaBeans [require a no-argument constructor](https://coderanch.com/t/634008/java/java-bean-blank-arg-constructor) to be present.

When a Java class has no constructors at all, there is a default no-arg constructor automatically added to it by the compiler.  The moment you define any constructor in the class, the default no-arg constructor goes away.

In your code, your `users` class defines such a constructor that contains arguments:

```
public users(String user_id, String address, String contact,String name) 
{}
```

As long as that constructor is present, and you don't define a no-arg constructor, that class will not have one.

To resolve this, you either need to remove that constructor from the class, or manually add a no-arg constructor to it:

```
public users() {}
```

Comment: wow thanks! appreciate it!

Comment: but by doing this i only retrieve the user ID, and all the data under the user ID such as name, address, etc is not retrieved.

Comment: Your class member names need to match the names of the children in the database.  Or you need to provide getters and setters that match in the JavaBeans fashion.

Comment: {
  
       "users" : {
    
       "73fsRy0znKRa5zFEl5XsJM4Q7Zf1" : {
      
        "address" : "Lokawi",
                      "contact" : "999",
                      "name" : "Logiut"
    },
    
 "QnHe3Y7LHQXnqrUT85v18PAKhbm1" : {
      
  "address" : "Papar",
      "contact" : "852,525,", 
"name" : "Bantaton"
    },
    
}

This is how the json data looks like, i've added another public users() but this time constructor, and the strings is as below: public class users { private String user_id, address, contact, name;

still only get the userID.

Comment: You might want to ask a second well-formatted question explaining this new problem you're running into.

Comment: hey sorry my misytake, its working now, thanks for your help dude