# How to retrieved data in Firebase to the Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. I need to retrieved data from database Firebase. But I have problem since when I  try to retrieve the data, the application will stop.
2. this is the code for retrievedPoint.java

   ```
   final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("reloadPoint");

   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           ReloadPoint rp = dataSnapshot.getValue(ReloadPoint.class);
           System.out.println(rp);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
       }
   });

   ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           ReloadPoint newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(ReloadPoint.class);
           System.out.println("Email: " + newPost.getmEmail());
           System.out.println("Point: " + newPost.getmPoint());
           System.out.println("User id: " + newPost.getmUserid());
       }

       @Override
       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
   ```
3. this the code for the ReloadPoint class.

   ```
   public class ReloadPoint {

   private String mEmail;
   private String mPoint;
   private String mUserid;

   public ReloadPoint(String email, String point, String userid) {
      this.mEmail = email;
      this.mPoint = point;
      this.mUserid = userid;

   }

   public String getmEmail() {
    return mEmail;
   }

   public void setmEmail(String mEmail) {
       this.mEmail = mEmail;
   }

   public String getmPoint() {
     return mPoint;
   }

   public void setmPoint(String mPoint) {
     this.mPoint = mPoint;
   }

   public String getmUserid() {
       return mUserid;
   }

   public void setmUserid(String mUserid) {
      this.mUserid = mUserid;
   }
   }
   ```
4. This is the thing that I want to retrieve from Firebase.
   [this is the child that I want to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzvKE.png)
5. This is the Android where the retrived data will appear if the retrieved process is success.[retrievedPoint.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmWlm.png)
6. Result from log cat.[Log cat result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j85Q.png)

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [users does not define no argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706601/users-does-not-define-no-argument-constructor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in fetching data from firebase to recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035276/error-in-fetching-data-from-firebase-to-recycler-view)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message implies, your `ReloadPoint` class needs a no-args constructor, e.g :

```
public ReloadPoint() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please include a no-argument constructor in your ReloadPoint class like so

```
public ReloadPoint() {

}
```

see this question [users does not define no argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706601/users-does-not-define-no-argument-constructor)

Comment: I put the code like you said above the apps working properly but the data cannot be retrieved @Dominic Orim

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReloadPoint {

private String mEmail;
private String mPoint;
private String mUserid;

//Ni hang lupa ni. apa la sakinah
//Klau da soklan lagi, hbungi kt insta id: nyrtron
public ReloadPoint(){

}

public ReloadPoint(String email, String point, String userid) {
   this.mEmail = email;
   this.mPoint = point;
   this.mUserid = userid;

}

public String getmEmail() {
 return mEmail;
}

public void setmEmail(String mEmail) {
    this.mEmail = mEmail;
}

public String getmPoint() {
  return mPoint;
}

public void setmPoint(String mPoint) {
  this.mPoint = mPoint;
}

public String getmUserid() {
    return mUserid;
}

public void setmUserid(String mUserid) {
   this.mUserid = mUserid;
}
}
```

I think I have found your problem.

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("reloadPoint").child("Waniyanazahri");
```

UPDATED ANSWER:
Its look like you haven't call the class.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      //Add this one
      ReloadPoint rp = new ReloadPoint();
      rp = dataSnapshot.getValue(ReloadPoint.class);
      System.out.println(rp);
    }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
   }
});
```

Comment: I did put the code that you said, and the application is working properly, but the data does not retrieved. @Zuhrain

Comment: @NorSakinah I updated the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I follow the code but it doesn't work and my app crashed. I checked the logcat, seem the  ReloadPoint newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(ReloadPoint.class);

Comment: @NorSakinah check the updated answer

Comment: I will update to you later.By the way, is the ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){} is needed to retrieve the data? @Zuhrain

Comment: actually, you just can use `addValueEventListener` only. I'm used to it. I know a little bit about the `addChildEventListener`. But most of my coding, I use `addValueEventListener` @NorSakinah

Comment: So can I just modify the code and delete 'addChildEventListener'? @Zuhrain

Comment: yes and don't forget to transfer all the value that you want to display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176097/discussion-between-nor-sakinah-and-zuhrain).