# ProGuard blocks constructor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

I am trying to disable ProgUard because it blocks my constructors on the Activities. This is the constructor:

```
public ChatFragmentAdapter(Context context, List<Users> user, boolean isChat) {
    this.context = context;
    this.user = user;
    this.isChat = isChat;
}
```

And this is the error that shows:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.selfcial.Models.Chat does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:570)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.example.selfcial.Adapters.ChatFragmentAdapter$2.onDataChange(ChatFragmentAdapter.java:154)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I tried to add `useProguard false` inside Gradle, but nothing changed. What can I do to solve this annoying error? Should I delete the whole file of ProGuard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [users does not define no argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706601/users-does-not-define-no-argument-constructor)

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks my constructors on the Activities"? Why did you paste a constructor for something that is neither an Activity nor the class in the error message?  Does the class in the error message have a no-argument constructor?

Comment: @RyanM I mean that when I run the app it crashes because of the above error. The class in the error message has a no-argument constructor but it still shows the error.

Comment: @Koenigsberg I tried this one but nothing changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you’re on the wrong path. Even though the exception message mentions ProGuard, the problem is explained in the first part of the message: *Class com.example.selfcial.Models.Chat does not define a no-argument constructor*

Adding a no-arg constructor to your class `Chat` should solve it:

```java
public Chat() {}
```